# Is it possible to instantiate a class which contains an injected enum

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, enums

Is it possible using `Microsoft`'s DI to `inject` an `enum`?

I am getting the following exception when instantiating a class which contains a `enum` in the `constructor`.

> InvalidOperationException: 
>           Unable to resolve service for type DependencyInjectionWithEnum.Domain.Types.TestType
>           while attempting to activate DependencyInjectionWithEnum.Domain.Service.TestService
>       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, bool throwIfCallSiteNotFound)

I have the following enum:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a test enum which is injected into the TestService's constructor
/// </summary>
public enum TestType
{
    First,
    Second,
    Third,
    Forth,
    Fifth
}
```

Which gets injected into the following

```
public class TestService
{
    private readonly TestType testType;

    /// <summary>
    /// Here I am injecting an enum called TestType
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="testType"></param>
    public TestService(TestType testType)
    {
        this.testType = testType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is a dummy method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string RunTest()
    {
        switch(testType.ToString().ToUpperInvariant())
        {
            case "First":
                return "FIRST";
            case "Second":
                return "SECOND";
            case "Third":
                return "THIRD";
            case "Forth":
                return "FORTH";
            case "Fifth":
                return "FIFTH";
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in Startup.cs I add the TestService to the ServiceCollection

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //mvc service
    services.AddMvc();

    // Setup the DI for the TestService
    services.AddTransient(typeof(TestService), typeof(TestService));

    //data mapper profiler setting
    Mapper.Initialize((config) =>
    {
        config.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
    });

    //Swagger API documentation
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "DependencyInjectionWithEnum 
 API", Version = "v1" });
    });
}
```

Finally I inject my TestService into my controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly TestService testService;

    /// <summary>
    /// Here I am injecting a TestService. The TestService is the class from which I am attempting to inject an enum
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="testService"></param>
    public TestController(TestService testService)
    {
        this.testService = testService;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dummy get
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(string))]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var testResult = testService.RunTest();

        return Ok(testResult);
    }
}
```

I get the `exception` when attempting to call the `controller`'s endpoint via `Swagger`.

**Tech Stack**

```
- Visual Studio v15.9.4 C# v7.3
 - Project Target Framework .NET Core 2.2
 - NuGet Packages 
   -        Microsoft.AspNetCore v2.2.0
   -        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc v2.2.0
   -        Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection v2.2.0
```

Comment: How is the type known to be injected

Comment: Everything is somehow possible, although unusual. Where is your enum registered to DI container? I can't see it in ConfigureServices.

Comment: I mean you need something like services.AddTransient(TestService), but for enums. :-)

Comment: Out of the box the enum can be added in the factory delegate when registering the service but it is still uncertain what it is you are trying to achieve as this looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

.

Comment: @AlKepp you are correct. In my example I don't have it injected. My original attempt "services.AddTransient(typeof(TestService), typeof(TestService)" to inject it failed with another exception.

Comment: @Nkosi this very well might be an XY problem. I was just curious to see how to do it. I am not sure injecting an enum is the best option anyway. The enum in my real project defines the behavior of a 3rd party api call (one I do not control). So because it is behavior I figured wanted to inject it. But that might not be the best option.

Comment: I figured it may have been a design issue. If you still have issues with the design choice feel free and post another question and see if the community can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible using Microsoft's DI to inject an enum?

**YES**

Out of the box the enum can be added with a factory delegate when registering the service at start up

```
// Setup the DI for the TestService
services.AddTransient<TestService>(sp => new TestService(TestType.First));
```

When injecting `TestService` into any dependents the container will use the factory delegate to resolve the class and its dependencies.

Comment: That was what I was looking for perfect. Thanks

Comment: The `new` keyword introduces a problem if `TestService` has injected other services which all services should be injected beside the `TestType.First`

Comment: @AhmadPayan sp in the factory delegate is IServiceProvider that can be used to resolve the other dependencies. `ActivatorUtilities` can be used to create the instance along with the service provider.

Comment: While this is a solution it doesn't answer the OP question because that way you're NOT injecting the enum; you just newing up stuff which is a whole other problem.